# Declaring and implementing a method that itself executes one line of code

Tags: objective-c

I've many times seen a case where a programmer needs to assign some value (Object or primitive type, does not matter). And let's say this value is an NSString and can be obtained from the following expression

```
[myObject description]// returns NSString
```

But for some reason I've seen many people declare another method that itself returns an NSString and executes the above command only. Like:

```
-(NSString*)getDescription{
   return [myObject description];
}
```

Is this just a matter of preference, or is is there some benefit from it?

Comment: Note that no method should have the `get*` prefix unless it follows a specific pattern (which this isn't).  It should just be `description`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this just a matter of preference, or is is there some benefit from it?

Those one line wrappers are often used to:

- introduce behavior of a method that is meant to be overridden
- or (more frequently) to simplify the program. If the method did not exist, you may find the complexity of the program grows. It serves to demonstrate intent, for clarity, documentation, and to minimize redundant implementations (simplifying the program).

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely some "benefit" of creating a method or even better, overriding the "standard" `NSObject` description method..

If you have a custom `NSObject` for example and override the `+(NSString *)description` method you can then return information directly inside that object.

Take for example the following was overwritten in the `NSObject` we called foo.

```
+ (NSString *)description {
     return @"Hello there";
}
```

Now, if you ever called `[foo description]` it would return the string "Hello there".
However, if you just returned description without overwriting the description method, it'd return something like `<foo>0x12234` or something.

So yeah, it definitely has a lot of benefit to overriding a custom `NSObject` description.